# Suspend the formatting of the logger, then go back to it

Tags: python, logging

I have a logging configuration where I log to a file and to the console:

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=logfile, filemode='w',
                        level=numlevel,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s')
    # add console messages
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    consoleformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    console.setFormatter(consoleformatter)
    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)
```

At some point in my script, i need to interact with the user by printing a summary and asking for confirmation. The summary is currently produced by prints in a loop. I would like to suspend the current format of the console logs, so that I can printout one big block of text with a question at the end and wait for user input. But i still want all of this to be logged to file!

The function that does this is in a module, where I tried the following :

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
def summaryfunc:
    logger.info('normal logging business')
    clearformatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    logger.setFormatter(clearformatter)
    logger.info('\n##########################################')
    logger.info('Summary starts here')
```

Which yields the error: `AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'setFormatter'`

I understand that a logger is a logger, not a handler, but i'm not sure on how to get things to work...

**EDIT**:

Following the answers, my problem turned into : how can i suspend logging to the console when interacting with the user, while still being able to log to file. IE: suspend only the streamHandler. Since this is happening in a module, the specifics of the handlers are defined elsewhere, so here is how i did it :

```
logger.debug('Normal logging to file and console')
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
stream_handler = root_logger.handlers[1]
root_logger.removeHandler(stream_handler)
print('User interaction')
logger.info('Logging to file only')
root_logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.info('Back to logging to both file and console')
```

This relies on the streamHandler always being the second in the list returned by `handlers` but i believe this is the case because it's in the order I added the handlers to the root logger...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with Vinay that you should use `print` for normal program output and only use `logging` for logging purpose. However, if you still want to switch formatting in the middle, then switch back, here is how to do it:

```
import logging

def summarize():
    console_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
    logger.info('Here is my report')
    console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)

numlevel = logging.DEBUG
logfile = 's2.log'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
console_handler.setFormatter(console_formatter)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile, mode='w')
file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s:%(funcName)s - %(message)s')
file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.info('Before summary')
summarize()
logger.info('After summary')
```

## Discussion

- The script creates a logger object and assigned to it two handlers: one for the console and one for file.
- In the function `summarize()`, I switched in a new formatter for the console handler, do some logging, then switched back.
- Again, let me remind that you should not use `logging` to display normal program output.

## Update

If you want to suppress console logging, then turn it back on. Here is a suggestion:

```
def interact():
    # Remove the console handler
    for handler in  logger.handlers:
        if not isinstance(handler, logging.FileHandler):
            saved_handler = handler
            logger.removeHandler(handler)
            break

    # Interact
    logger.info('to file only')

    # Add the console handler back
    logger.addHandler(saved_handler)
```

Note that I did not test the handlers against `logging.StreamHandler` since a `logging.FileHandler` is derived from `logging.StreamHandler`. Therefore, I removed those handlers that are not `FileHandler`. Before removing, I saved that handler for later restoration.

## Update 2: .handlers = []

In the main script, if you have:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # __name__ == '__main__'
```

Then in a module, you do:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__) # __name__ == module's name, not '__main__'
```

The problem is, in the script, `__name__ == '__main__'` and in the module, `__name__ == <the module's name>` and not `'__main__'`. In order to achieve consistency, you will need to make up some name and use them in both places:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('MyScript')
```

Comment: First of all thanks A LOT for this answer, it makes things much clearer. Also : I'm ditching basicConfig and doing it this way now ! I have edited my comment following your and Vinay's answers : it works but i'm unsure if it's the best way (especially calling out to the root logger from within a module)

Comment: Please see my update where I suggest a way to suppress the console handler, then restore it.

Comment: I see. That's much better :) One last question though : in my code `logger.handlers` is empty : i have to use `for handler in logging.getLogger().handlers:`. At the start of the module I do `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: At first, did you call `logging.addHandler()` or `logger.addHandler()`?

Comment: In the program itself I do use `file_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename=logfile, mode='w')` then `logger.addHandler(file_handler)`. In the module I just do `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` at the begining. The strange thing is that in the module logger.hasHandlers() is true but logger.handler is empty... I moved the handler manipulation to the program where it does works on logger.

Comment: OK, got it ! Tested it and it works but i have a new problem : that module is called by different programs, each will have a different name in the logging.getLogger, so i don't know how to be consistent in the module itself because depending on the caller the name will be different.

Answer (score 3):

Logging shouldn't be used to provide the actual output of your program - a program is supposed to run the same way if logging is turned off completely. So I would suggest that it's better to do what you were doing before, i.e. prints in a loop.

Comment: That is an excellent point : i will log this info to file but independently of user interaction. Thanks for your answer !